# Extract the values between spaces in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to extract values between spaces in excel and wondering how i do that.

I have already tried to use

```
=TRIM((MID(E117,FIND(" ",E117)+1,FIND(" ",E117,FIND(" ",E117)+1)-(FIND(" ",E117)))))
```

which works fine for the first value after a space, but I am not sure how to reference the next space.

What I need to do is extract values from the string:
`S EP M to BG 1 DIR`

I need a separate column for each of the following: `S`, `EP`, `M`, `BG`

[image: Screenshot of data]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hii @MichaelC,, still is confusing better [edit] your post and load some screen shot ,,, like the original data and expected results,,, !

Comment: Hey @MichaelC,, for column E, use Text to Column command and pick SPACE as criteria to SPLIT the text !

Comment: Hi @RajeshS i need to do this with a formula for each cell, this way i can have a sheet where i paste the raw data and this section where i have the split values (which in my case are codes i use for certain locations)

Comment: Hi @MichaelC,, now check my post I've shown formula and other method too,, believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add a column and use LEFT and RIGHT functions to get the result, I will give a answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since you are in need of the formula, therefore I would like to suggest this to use:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- You need to insert Helper values in L1:S1, depends number of text/words separated by space.
- Formula in cell L2:

  ```
  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($K2," ",REPT(" ",LEN($K2))),(L$1-1)*LEN($K2)+1,LEN($K2)))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Fill forrmula across the range.
- This formula can be used when text/words are separated by other delimiters, like Comma/Slash/Dash sign.
- Edit this part `SUBSTITUTE($K2,","`
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

---

*Another possible method is Text to Column wizard.*

- Select data in K2:K4.
- From Data TAB hit Text to Column.
- Select option Delimited.
- On next screen click Space.
- From next screen, select Destination cell & finish with Ok.

Comment: Glad to help you @MichaelC ,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Give a try in VBA (Set value of `j` variable to end column number)

```
Function Calc()
  Dim Cols as String
  Dim j As Integer 
  Dim strCell as Variant 
  Dim arrValues
  j = 6
  Cols = "E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
  Cols = Split(Cols," ")
  For k = 1 To j 
    strCell = Range("E" & k).Value
    arrValues = Split(strCell," ")
    For Each strValue in arrValues
      Range(Cols(k) & k).Value = arrValues(k)
    Next
  Next
End Function
```